# Result of MAX()- method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have table tb_Orders (it empty), which have fields^
- order_id (int) (primary key)
- order_date nchar(30)

In my application, when client make order, requests the function:

```
private int GetNewOrderId()

    {
        int ord_id = 0;

        if (db.tb_Orders.Max(x => x.order_id) != null)
        {
            int ord = db.tb_Orders.Max(x => x.order_id);
            ord_id = ord + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ord_id = 1;
        };

        return ord_id;
    }
```

which get the new order id (+1 to max order in table).

Operator "if" must, when the table is still empty, get id = 1;

But the result - error (when I try to get id).

ERROR TEXT: "Error converting cast a value type "Int32", as materialize value is null."

Answer (score 2):

Try casting your `order_id` to a nullable integer when making the `Max` call:

```
private int GetNewOrderId()
{
    int nextOrderId = db.tb_Orders.Max(x => (int?)x.order_id) ?? 1;
    return nextOrderId;
}
```

You will also notice that in my example there's only a single SQL query to the database whereas you were making 2: one in the if statement and another one inside.

Comment: I'd suggest `collection.Max(x=>(Int32?)x.order_id) ?? 0` and `return nextOrderId + 1`

Comment: Sure, why not. It's just that I am lazy and prefer to avoid an additional line of code in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `order_id` is `Nullable<int>`. Use the `Value` property to get it's value, and you can also perform the query before `if` statement and don't execute the query twice:

```
var max = db.tb_Orders.Max(x => x.order_id);
if(max != null)
{
    int ord = max.Value;
    ord_id = ord + 1;
}
```

Comment: I very highly doubt that a primary key (such as `order_id` in this example) would be declared as a nullable integer. And if by some chance this was the case then this would be a very serious design flaw.

Comment: The method MAX return the value, which type is the type of argument (order_id). If my table is empty then result of the db.tb_Orders.Max(x => x.order_id) is NULL, but field is primary key, and it can't be null (return the null value of function)